# pycharm can't run .py using remote ssh python interpreter on WSL for encoding

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I configure my pycharm to use remote ssh python interpreter on the WSL (windows subsystem for linux) in the same computer to run python program. but it seems to encounter encoding problem. I change all the file_encoding to 'utf8', but don't work.

*raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yanhui/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py", line 74, in search_function
  entry = _cache.get(encoding, _unknown)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'*

[image]

here is pycharm encoding config:
[image]

ssh remote interpreter works correctly:
[image]

Comment: check here? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Answer (score 9):

go to the Settings->Tools->Python Scientific and uncheck "Show plots in toolwindow"

Comment: Something to do with trying to display the plots on a system that doesn't support graphics, I think.